# Why do we use initializer_list in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, initializer-list

I read `initializer_list` is for functions taking an unknown number of arguments of a single type. But why do we need it? Why can't we use normal containers instead, like `vector` or `list`?

I tried the following code, and it works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void f(const list<string> &slst)
{
    for (auto s : slst)
        cout << s << endl;
}

int main()
{
    f({ "Good", "morning", "!" });
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That code works _because_ `std::list` has a constructor taking a `std::initializer_list`...

Answer (score 7):

While your code does not explicitly mention it, you are actually using an `initializer_list` in the [constructor of `list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list):

```
list( std::initializer_list<T> init, 
      const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Indeed, you are probably more likely to use standard library containers that accept initializer lists in their constructors (e.g. `std::vector`, `std::list`) than writing functions with `std::initializer_list` arguments yourself. Another example in the standard library are aggregation functions like `std::min` and `std::max` that compute a single value from an arbitrary number of input values.

However, there are cases where you might want to use it for your own functions, e.g. for the constructor of a data structure that you implement yourself, or for your own aggregation function. While these things would also be possible with `std::vector` or `std::list`, the most straightforward way with the smallest overhead is to use `std::initializer_list`.

Answer (score 5):

In a nutshell:

`int x[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };` has always existed ever since C.

However, `int x[]` is problematic because:

1. it's not a type, so it can't support member functions
2. it's not copyable

So now we have `std::array<int, 3> x = { 1, 2, 3 };` which is a class, so it can have member functions and is copyable. And it has initialisation notation that is consistent with a c array, which is a *good thing*.

It turns out that this is also a useful way of initialising maps, sets, vectors, unordered_maps and so on.

The mechanism to make this happen is the `std::initializer_list<T>`, which translates the literal of `{ 1, 2, 3 }` into an object with a size, begin and end so it can be traversed.

This makes for easier and more intuitive coding. Because in c++03, the equivalent of this:

```
std::vector<int> x = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

is this:

```
std::vector<int> make_vector()
{
  std::vector<int> result;
  result.reserve(3);
  result.push_back(1);
  result.push_back(2);
  result.push_back(3);
  return result;
};

std::vector<int> x = make_vector();
```

Which I think you'd agree, totally sucks!

Comment: `std::array` and `std::initializer_list` are orthogonal; the former is an aggregate.

Comment: “it's not a type“??

Comment: @T.C. "object" might be a better word.

Comment: @T.C. actually, what is the right name for the thing it's not? Saying that "arrays are just a bit gimped" doesn't sound professional :)

Comment: "it doesn't have class type", perhaps?

Comment: `int[3]` certainly is a type and `x` certainly is an object. I agree with TC that you're looking for _"`int[3]` is not a class"_.

Answer (score 2):

Initializer lists are **not** there to replace containers, but to **initialize** them.

Your example would look different without them.

```
int main()
{
    list<string> l;
    l.insert("Good");
    l.insert("Morning");
    l.insert("!");
    f(list);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

One point of initializer lists is to be able to initialize containers in the construction.

Answer (score 2):

`initializer_list` is a view-wrapper around a `const` automatically constructed C-style array.

It stores a pointer to begin and a pointer to one-past the end.

Your use of `{}` uses`std::initializer_list`: that is how your `std::list` got the 3 elements!  Marshalling it into a `std::list` then iterating on it is extra indirection with costs (heap allocation, extra copies).

Using an `initializer_list` directly in `f` would avoid those extra costs, giving you access to the raw array of 3 elements your `{}` use created.

Basically, `std::initializer_list` is the library component of the langage component that permits non-C-style arrays to get access to a list of elements all the same type created via a simple `{}`.

You only occasionally use them to replace containers, mainly during an initialization-like operation, as the lifetime of the array cannot be extended beyond that of the initially created list.  You must copy it out if you want a more complex lifetime for the data than that.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `f` with `std::initializer_list` as argument there is an implicit conversion to `std::list`. If you overload `f` creating another function `void f(std::initializer_list<string>)` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void f(const list<string> &slst)
{
    cout << "1st called" << endl;
}

void f(const initializer_list<string> &slst)
{        
    cout << "2nd called" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    f({ "Good", "morning", "!" });
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

`2nd called` will be printed because with second `f` conversion not needed.