# Initialize custom collection with list of values

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I have created a class that should act as a collection (with some custom behavior of mine).
Inside, the class contains an array, to store the values.

```
class MyCollection {

private:         
    int m_array[N];

public:

    int operator [] (int idx) const {
        return m_array[idx];
    }
    
    int operator [] (TKey k) {
        return m_array[idx];
    }
};
```

I would like to be able to initialize an instance of this class like it can be done with arrays, but I don't know how to do it, or what this kind of initialization is called ot then look on the web.

```
std::array<int, 3> a2 = {1, 2, 3};
```

How can this be achieved?
Please note that I may change the type of the elements of the collection (even template it), the referred `int` is just an example.

Comment: why are you not using `std::array<int,N>` ? What is `N` ?

Comment: You're looking for `std::initializer_list`

Comment: You can add a constructor with a `std::initializer_list` I will show you some code below.

Comment: See [Why use initializer_list instead of vector in parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414832/why-use-initializer-list-instead-of-vector-in-parameters) and [Why do we use initializer_list in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512381/why-do-we-use-initializer-list-in-c11)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'm not using an array, because I want to introduce additional behavior that an std::array does not provide.

Comment: but the c-array does not provide this addtional behavior either. I was suggesting to use `std::array` as member of your `MyCollection`, it avoids a lot of problems

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Because it's too slow :)

Comment: @AmiguelS what is slow? A `std::array<int,N>` is just a `int[N]` nothing more, only some quirk removed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The std::initializer_list will be your friend.

We can add it in a constructor, but also in an assignment operator, or any other member function.

Please read about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Code could look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

class MyCollection {
private:
    int m_array[10]{};
public:
    MyCollection(const std::initializer_list<int> il) {
        if (il.size() <= 10) {
            size_t i{};
            for (const int& t : il) m_array[i++] = t;
        }
    }
    int operator [] (size_t idx) const {
        return m_array[idx];
    }
};
int main() {
    MyCollection mc {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    for (size_t i{}; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << mc[i] << '\n';
}
```